# Update database using mySQL & php PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo

I've created a database for one of my classes simulating a hotel reservation form.
my database table name that I am trying to get values from is tblNameRes and the fields are fldName and pkEmail
I have gotten the values from the database and displayed them in this table here: 
http://www.uvm.edu/~cchessia/cs148/assign4/strugg.php

I want to add a column to be able to update and delete these records, but I don't really understand how.  I have this code:

```
$updating = $db->prepare('UPDATE `tblNameRes` SET `name` = `name` + ? WHERE `id` = ?');
$updating->execute(array(20, $id));
```

but I want to be able to click a link that says "update" and it will take me to another page that allows me to edit the data and submit it back to the database.  I would also like to be able to delete the data in the same way.

Comment: Is there a reason you are starting with PHP rather than NodeJS?

Comment: yeah, my class focuses on php and mySQL

Comment: Shame.  NodeJS is the future.   I would recommend rendering the contents of the array within the page and the. Just posting it back

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused to what you would like, would you like the PDO code to both update and delete items from your DB? If so I use this, I'm also new to PDO. Also try not to use ' around table/field names.

```
/** Code to update */

$query = "UPDATE tblNameRes SET name ='$name' WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->BindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

/** Code to delete */

$query = "DELETE FROM tblNameRes WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->BindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Let me know if this helps, or is not what you wanted. I'm new here so I can't post 'comments'.

Comment: why you're planting an SQL injection in almost every example?

Answer (score 0):

/* code for update  and remove this 'at the beginning an at the end*/

`$query = "UPDATE tblNameRes SET name =:fname WHERE id = :id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->BindValue('fname',$fname);
$stmt->execute();`